# Map all returns of virtual functions to their corresponding return addresses

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, lto

basically I want to do caller/callee mapping by adding runtime checks
which checks for the allowed ranges before each C/C++ return is
executed.

I have a forward mapping of all virtual object dispatches to the
allowed virtual table entries for a given class hierarchy.
This data is collected during LLVM LTO. Now I want to do the same for
all the virtual function returns. Since the forward mapping is telling
me which functions should be accessible I need to determine in order
to precisely map backward the following information.

1. From where in Clang/LLVM to get the return addresses for each
   return contained in a virtual function. Is it possible to be obtained
   this information during compile time?
2. How to determine in which function a certain return is contained.
   Next how to determine to which class that function belongs to?

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: 1. Of course not: the return address is pushed onto the stack at runtime; not available at compile time. 2. I cannot makenhead or tail of this question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

yes EJP you are right that the return addresses are pushed during run-time onto the stack but each return should return to the address next to the call instruction which was used to call the corresponding function so I was thinking that since each return has to continue execution after the call instruction there (after the call instruction) should be an address which is obtainable during compile time.

If the above does not hold than what about instruction the compiler that he generates the needed information after each call instruction?

Looking forward for a qualified precise answer to my post. :)